# JACC Policy Provider:Failed Permission Check permission (" ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "setPolicy") ")

Tags: glassfish-3, access-denied, group-policy, jacc

If I deploy my jsf2.0 web app on glassfish3.1.2 it is working fine and login mechanism is working fine. But same app when i am trying to deploy on glassfish3.1.2 on my colleagues machine at the time of login it is giving JACC permission check failure error. May i know how can i stop JACC permissions getting invoked? granted.policy file get generated inside generated folder. also programmatically i dont write any policy for my application.

```
JACC Policy Provider:Failed Permission Check: context (" Advocates/Advocates ") , permission ("     ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "setPolicy") ") 
SEVERE: JACC: Unexpected security exception on access decision
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.security.AccessControlException: access     denied          ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "setPolicy")

granted.policy
/* AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED ON Tue Jul 17 17:14:36 PDT 2012*/
/* DO NOT EDIT */
 grant {
      permission javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission "/";
      permission javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission "/";
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using EJB look up for the same reason I have added,

```
System.setSecurityManager(new java.rmi.RMISecurityManager());
```

which was causing problem, after commenting this line application is working fine.